# ocmod modify both admin and catalog files using braces

Tags: php, opencart2.x

How come my ocmod isn't working using the braces?

```
<file path="{admin,catalog}/model/tool/upload.php">
    <operation error="skip">
        <search index="0">
            <![CDATA[public function addUpload(]]>
        </search>
        <add position="below">
            <![CDATA[...]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

If I change the path to `<file path="catalog/model/tool/upload.php">` it works.

https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System

```
Using braces allows for selecting multiple files and not having to repeat the code operation multiple times.

<file path="system/{engine,library}/{action,loader,config,language}*.php">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: Wildcard paths were silently broken in OpenCart 2.0.2.0.The new method is **coma separated** full paths:

```
<file path="system/{engine,library}/{action,loader,config,language}*.php,">
```

Will be written as

```
<file path="system/engine/action.php,system/engine/loader.php,system/library/config.php,system/library/language.php">
```